# Passing Multiple Parameters to Laravel Resource Collection

Tags: laravel

I am creating an API via apiResource with following code being passed to the resource collection

```
$coupons=Coupons:paginate(15);
$brand='brand1';
$brand_id='123';

return CouponResource::collection($coupons);
```

I am passing `$coupons` variable to the Resource Collection. But i want to pass `$brand` and `$brand_id` too.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the meaning - `Coupons:paginate(15);`?

Comment: You must have `$coupons->brand` and `$coupons->brand_id`. Otherwise you may pass an array with these values.

Comment: I did this ` $br=[
            'aff_id'=>$aff_id,
            'brand'=>$brand,
        ];
return CouponResource::collection($coupons,compact($br));

and but i am not able to access $br in Resource file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have created a relationship for brand you can use that

```
 $coupons=Coupons::with('brand')->paginate(15);
```

or you can use appended parameters in your Coupons model

```
 $appends =['brand_id','brand'];
```

and then

```
 public function getBrandIdAttribute(){
   return $this->brand()->id;
 }
 public function getBrandAttribute(){
   return $this->brand()->name;
 }
```

Comment: There is no relationship available for Brand & Brandid in the Coupon Model

Comment: hope brand is related or do you find the brand some other way .. if you specify i can tell you how to add it

Comment: There is no relation of Brand & Coupon. i am getting Brand from somewhere else

Comment: ok can you tell he how you find the brand for a particular coupon

Comment: Brand will remain same for all the coupons.

Comment: I tried to map the collection but that removes the pagination.

Comment: you can use the second method i mentioned(appending parameters to Coupon model) and return the brand and brand_id values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167315/discussion-between-athul-raj-and-mohit).